# obtener datos de nodos hermanos XML con python

Tags: python, xml, archivo

Tengo un archivo XML que he leído con la librería xml.dom dentro de python.
Mi situación es que mi archivo tiene varios nodos llamados Producto que a su vez tiene dos nodos llamados origen y terminal.
El primer producto pertenece a un nodo padre llamado Union1 y el segundo a Union2

```
<Unión1>
  <Producto>
    <origen>
       <Terminal> 123 </Terminal>
       <Terminal> 123 </Terminal>
       <Terminal> 123 </Terminal>
    </origen>
</Producto>
</Unión1>
<Union2>
<Producto>
    <origen>
       <Terminal> 567 </Terminal>
       <Terminal> 567 </Terminal>
       <Terminal> 567 </Terminal>
       <Terminal> 567 </Terminal>
       <Terminal> 567 </Terminal>
       <Terminal> 567 </Terminal>
    </origen>
</Producto>
</Union2>
```

Los productos son diferentes.
De favor me pueden comentar cómo acceder a los datos del nodo terminal. Al hacer el parse se realiza la referencia a los dos productos:

```
docs=xml.getElementsByTagName("PRODUCTO")
[<DOM Element: PRODUCTO at 0x16f31e31f70>,
<DOM Element: PRODUCTO at 0x16f32648e50>]
```

Pero al acceder me marcar el error fuera de rango:

```
for prod in prods:
   TerminalL=prod.getElementsByTagName("Terminal")[0]
   TerminalL=PermisoTransporteL.firstChild.data
```

También se me ha complicado obtener en una sola iteración el nodo Terminal ya que el total de los mismos es diferentes en Unon1 y Union2

De favor me pueden apoyar con sus consejos.

Answer (score 0):

No debería mostrarte un error de indexado a no ser que tengas algún nodo `Producto` sin ningún nodo `Terminal`. No obstante, si quieres obtener todos los nodos, en vez de indexar usa un ciclo `for`:

```py
from xml.dom import minidom 
from io import StringIO

data  = StringIO("""
    <root>
      <Unión1>
        <Producto>
          <origen>
             <Terminal> 123 </Terminal>
             <Terminal> 123 </Terminal>
             <Terminal> 123 </Terminal>
          </origen>
        </Producto>
      </Unión1>
      <Union2>
        <Producto>
            <origen>
               <Terminal> 567 </Terminal>
               <Terminal> 567 </Terminal>
               <Terminal> 567 </Terminal>
               <Terminal> 567 </Terminal>
               <Terminal> 567 </Terminal>
               <Terminal> 567 </Terminal>
            </origen>
        </Producto>
      </Union2>
    </root>
""")

xml = minidom.parse(data) 
prods = xml.getElementsByTagName("Producto")
for prod in prods:
    print(prod)
    terminals = prod.getElementsByTagName("Terminal")
    for terminal in terminals:
        print(terminal.firstChild.data)
```

La salida seria algo así:

```
<DOM Element: Producto at 0x7fbff8794550>
 123 
 123 
 123 
<DOM Element: Producto at 0x7fbff87979d0>
 567 
 567 
 567 
 567 
 567 
 567
```

Ignora a `io.StringIO`, es solo para emular un archivo a partir de una cadena y hacer el ejemplo fácilmente reproducible.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu apoyo. La variable de la referencia a prod.getElementsByTAgname para Terminal la estaba realizando fuera del primer ciclo for. Nuevamente, muchas gracias por el apoyo, me quedó muy claro el ejemplo y me sirvió para seguir con mi código. Saludos